# App works fine on Localhost, but has NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to Ruby and now experiencing an error after deploying my app to Heroku.

I test my app on localhost and everything works fine; however, when I try to save a new post, I have "undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass" on Heroku. I have searched for solutions on StackOverflow but so far I haven't found anything.

Error I got from heroku logs:

```
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412066+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass):
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412076+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb:22:in `create'
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412074+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/post.rb:37:in `save_with_initial_vote'
2015-04-01T03:37:23.407819+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412070+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/vote.rb:20:in `update_post'
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412078+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412063+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412068+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/post.rb:30:in `update_rank'
2015-04-01T03:37:23.412072+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/post.rb:39:in `block in save_with_initial_vote'
```

From the logs, it looks like the problem is from update_rank method in post.rb.

From my app/models/post.rb:

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic

  default_scope { order('rank DESC') }
  scope :visible_to, ->(user) { user ? all : joins(:topic).where('topics.public' => true) }

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 20 }, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true

    def update_rank
        age_in_days = (created_at - Time.new(1970,1,1)) / (60 * 60 * 24)
        new_rank = points + age_in_days

        update_attribute(:rank, new_rank)
      end

      def save_with_initial_vote
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          post = Post.create
          user.votes.create(value: 1, post: self)
        end
      end
```

From app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.topic = @topic
        authorize @post

    if @post.save_with_initial_vote
      flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

models/vote.rb:

```
after_save :update_post

  def up_vote?
    value == 1
  end

  def down_vote?
    value == -1
  end

  def update_post
    post.update_rank
  end
```

I have run "heroku rn db:migrate" and "heroku restart" but the error still exists. My rails version is 4.2.0 and my Ruby version is 2.0.0.

Does anyone know what is the cause and how to make it work on Heroku?

Comment: Where is update_post being called?

Comment: @Antarr Byrd: after_save  :update_post in models/vote.rb, I have also added it in my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only use of "-" in the code provided is in first line of *Post#update_rank*

Note, when I run the following in irb

```
irb> (nil - Time.new(1970,1,1)) / (60  * 60 * 24)
```

I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

Remember everything in Ruby a class. Many classes implement the operator methods. The DateTime class does, but the NilClass does not.

I suspect your created_at is not yet set and at this point is a nil value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The created_at is in db/schema.rb: 
    {create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"}   

Not sure if I missed anything.

Comment: Rails sets the created_at when the object is successfully saved to the database. Do you have any validators defined that might cause the post save to fail?

Comment: I just added the validators in my question but it doesn't seem it has issue with "created_at" to me.

Comment: Add *puts "update_rank:created_at = #{created_at}"* as the first line of *update_rank* and push the changes to Heroku. In the Heroku log file, *heroku logs -t* check to see what value created_at is set to.

Comment: You are right~~~Thank you so much! The issue has been fixed by deleting all the "null: false" after each "created_at" under _db:schema.rb_, and make sure the new posts meet all the validation under _post.rb_, the new posts are all passed on Heroku now.